# Get minimum number of shots required so that goals over shots is the percentage given

Tags: c++, loops, c++11, while-loop

I am having some difficulty understanding why an extremely simple program I've coded in C++ keeps looping. I'll describe the problem at hand first just to check if maybe my solution is incorrect and then I'll write the code:

The shooting efficiency of a soccer player is the percentage of
goals scored over all the shots on goal taken in all his professional career. It is a rational number between 0 and 100,
rounded to one decimal place. For example, a player who
made 7 shots on goal and scored 3 goals has a shooting
efficiency of 42.9.
Given the shooting efficiency of a player, we want to know which
is the minimum amount of shots on goal needed to get that
number (which must be greater than 0).

What I thought of is that if p is the percentage given, then in order to get the minimum number of shots n, the relationship n*p <= n must be satisfied since n*p would be the number of goals scored over a total of n.

I've coded the following program:

```
int main(){
    float efficiency;
    cin >> efficiency;
    int i = 1;
    float tries = i*efficiency;

    while(tries > i){
        i++;
        tries = i*efficiency;
    }

    cout << i << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This program never terminates since it keeps looping inside the while, any suggestions on what might be wrong would be really appreciated.

Comment: Check your math. `np <= n` simplifies to `p <= 1` when `n` is positive (which you say it must be). Changing the value of `n` has no effect.

Comment: I suppose the efficiency is expressed as the percentage and therefore has a value between 0 and 100 (not between 0 and 1). With an efficiency>1%, the product `i*efficiency` will always be greater than `i`. The algorithm therefore never exits the loop.

Comment: You completely ignore the "rounded to one decimal place" thing. It's not going to implement itself.

Comment: This is actually an interesting mathematical problem. [Here's the answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Best_rational_within_an_interval), but you'll have to translate it into code.

Answer (score 0):

You multiply efficiency after incrementing i. This means efficiency will grow much faster than i as when i increases by 1, efficiency will increase (i+1) times, ending up much larger than i.